# Swapping routers resulting in ARP issues?

Tags: cisco, arp

A day ago I tried to swap out a router with a Meraki MX-84 Gateway in order to test the Meraki's VPN functionality.

I set the static IP configuration on the MX-84's Internet interface to be the same as was configured on the original router's Internet interface, but it would not connect to the Meraki cloud.

So I tried reconnecting the original router and it would no longer pass traffic.

A packet capture between on the link between the original router and the ISP shows the original router sending ARP requests and receiving a reply from the upstream router. However, no traffic came back from the upstream router.

In an attempt to get connectivity working again I removed the original router and installed a 3rd router from a different vendor.

That router works fine.

So I tried reconnecting the original router again and it still didn't work.

Configuring the static IP on a laptop and connecting it to the ISP link worked.

I ended up resetting the original router back to factory defaults AND setting the MAC address of the internet facing interface to be the same as the third router I connected. That works.

I tried restoring the original router's configuration and just changing the MAC address on the Internet interface. That does not work.

Needlessly to say, I'm stumped. I had made no configuration changes to the original router's configuration. I should have been able to plug it back into the ISP link and have it working.

Questions:

1. Has anyone seen a similar issue caused by a Meraki Gateway?
2. Why would changing the MAC address of the original router make a difference?

I suspect the issue may be some sort of ARP issue on the upstream router side, or that the ISP was blocking the original MAC address of the original router, but after a couple of phone calls with the ISP, they assure me that the issue is not on their end.

Thanks.

Comment: You could improve your question by editing it to add more details. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful when editing your question. Primarily configurations that worked/didn't work.

Comment: Delving a bit more into the "off topic" parts of this, it sounds to me like the ISP had a "stale" ARP entry. Some of your devices may have sent gratuitous ARPs for the Internet facing interface updating the ARP entry that your first router was not doing. You could try manually sending a GARP from the first router to see if that would work, some basic guidance [here](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/ARP#Gratuitous_ARP). But this is all just pure conjecture at this point.

Comment: Good suggestion, I tried the GARP but it didn't work. The upstream router just doesn't seem to like the old router's MAC address